# taking csv information, sorting and producing numpy array (python

Tags: python, csv, numpy

I'm trying to define a function that takes two inputs, instructions and actions for a car, which are lists of strings that contain the name of the CSV files to be opened that contain data (I cannot use the csv library import). The csv files contain data in columns in the format; action, time, speed. e.g N, 10, 10 means North for 10 seconds at 10 meters per second. the displacement would then be 100 north etc.

Say the first instr1.csv file contains (no header):

```
N, 10, 10 
E, 10, 8 
S, 10, 5
W, 10, 4
```

Ultimately I want to return the vertical and horizontal displacements for the car and then the total distance in numpy arrays. I keep getting stuck trying to figure out how when the action is North, I take the 2nd column and 3rd column, multiply them by each other, append it to a list and then create a numpy list to be returned.

First I read the data, loops over each row to produce data, then create a structured array (arrayInstructionsFile1) with dtypes.

What I've got so far is:

```
import numpy as np
#import matplotlib.pyplot as plt #(plot numpy arrays later)


def car(instructions,actions):

    instrucFile = instructions
    newArrayFile1 = []
    newArrayFile2 = []
    lstNorth = []

    for file in instrucFile[0:1]:    #reads first csv file
        with open(file) as filedata: #get data
            arrayInstructionsFile1 = np.genfromtxt(file,delimiter=',',dtype=[('action','U1'),('time',float),('speed',float)],encoding=None,usecols=None)
            for i in arrayInstructionsFile1:      #loops each row to a list
                newArrayFile1.append(i)
            npArrInstrucDataFile1 = np.array(newArrayFile1) #prints structured array

    print('File1 structured array = ',npArrInstrucDataFile1)
```

now using the function like this:

```
car(['instr1.csv','instr2.csv'],['act1.csv','act2.csv'])
```

gives the structured array:

```
File1 structured array =  [('N', 10., 10.) ('E', 10.,  8.) ('S', 10.,  5.) ('W', 10.,  4.)]
```

but I'm confused, how do I tell python to put the values into a new array depending on whether the action is N,E,S or W, and then multiply the floats by each other so I can return the required numpy arrays?

as you can see I am struggling greatly with this, so any help/guidance or perhaps even suggesting a better approach would be very very appreciated. I have tried to explain everything i'm trying to do to avoid confusion, sorry if it's a bit long!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood you correctly, your file is something like a simple LOGO programm (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logo_(programming_language))

You can "play" the "programm" the folowing way:

1) Define x and y variables, at the begining they should be zero, that means "no displacements"

2) Decide, how your directions (N, E, S, W) would apply to the X-Y coordinate system, for example, north direction is positive Y, south is negative Y, east is a positive X, and west is a negative X

3) For each action, check, what should be done, acording to your decision in point 2:

If action is "N", you should add speed * time to the **y** variable.
(where speed and time are taken from your 2nd and 3rd columns)

```
y += speed * time
```

if action is "W", substract speed * time from "x" variable

```
x -= speed * time
```

and so on for "E" and "S"

By "for each" I mean, that you should walk through your data-grid row-by-row, and for each row take an action. For example:

```
for row in file1_structured_array:
    action  = row[0]
    speed = float(row[1])
    time = float(row[2])
    if action == "N":
        y += speed * time
    elif action == "S":
        ...
    elif action == "E":
        ...
    elif action == "W":
        ...
```

4) At the end of this execution you'll have horizontal displacement in your **x** variable, and vertical displacement in your **y** variable. Also, you can find distance with help of Pythagorean theorem.

5) This results could be easily put into python or numpy array of your needs.

Comment: Sadly I can only use python as the language to write the function, and can't use libraries such as importing csv, which makes it a little bit more difficult. I understand steps 1) and 2) (I was going to these after reading and manipulating data, should I do this first?) however I'm really struggling with 3), After the data is in the array, how can I check the entire array for the action (e.g what about two 'N' actions?) ? I have something like this but It just makes me more confused.    if npArrInstrucDataFile1[np.where(npArrInstrucDataFile1['action'] == 'N')] in npArrInstrucDataFile1:

Comment: You don't need to use external libraries for what I've proposed. Also, python's csv isn't a external one, it's part of python standart library, and if you have python installed, you automatically have csv too.

Comment: I've updated answer to make it easier to understand what I mean

Comment: Thank you so much, this clears everything up for me. I knew there was a better way and had a feeling I was just over complicating the problem. You have saved me hours of confusion and frustration, thank you again.